# How to find on which resource group my webapp is running using node js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

- I have a node.js microservice running on azure webapp.

  - I have two different resource group in azure `dev` and `prod`
  - I have two different config file in that microservice let say `devConfig` and `prodConfig` both have a different configuration for the respective environment.

I want to find on which resource group my webapp is running, so that if its dev I fetch the details from `devConfig` and same for `prodConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an environment variable in each webapp and make it return dev in dev and prod in prod

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure

Get env variable in node:

```
process.env.ENV_VARIABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Can you please provide me some code snippet or some link. It will be helpful for me to code.

Comment: I have no idea about node.js, but creating an App Settings is really easy

Comment: Yes i have already created the environment variable in azure as per mention [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure#howtochangeconfig). But I have no idea how can I pick these up using node js

Comment: have you looked at the answer?

Comment: Yes, Thanks I am working on the approach u mention above.

Comment: Hello, Can you please provide some code snippet on `process.env.ENV_VARIABLE_NAME` to find out on which environment our code is running

Comment: just like i said - no. I'm not a node.js guy, but I believe a simple if statement would work